# SQL Query: SELECT MAX SUM quantity

Tags: sql

How do i combine a SUM and MAX in a single query?

Lets say i have a orderrule:

ProductID \ Quantity

I Could say:

```
Select ProductID,SUM(Quantity) AS Sold 
FROM Orderrule 
GROUP BY ProductID
ORDER BY SUM(Quantity) Desc
```

However that would return all sales, and not just the most sold product (with quantity).

Comment: whats wrong with a `top 1`

Comment: These answers are using `TOP` which is a MSSQL keyword.  It would be `LIMIT` for MySql and others.  Please tag your question with the appropriate database platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 ProductID, Sold FROM
(
  SELECT ProductID, SUM(Quantity) AS Sold
  FROM Orderrule
  GROUP BY ProductID
) totals
ORDER BY Sold DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT TOP(1)
*
FROM
(
    Select 
        ProductID,
        MAX(Quantity) As MaxQuantity,
        SUM(Quantity) AS Sold 
    FROM Orderrule 
    GROUP BY ProductID    
)AS X
ORDER BY Sold DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

So there are two ways to do it - first to have a limit on the number of results, something likes:

```
select * from (your_select) where rownum = 1
```

the other one is to pick the one with the the highest value, which will require a subselect, something like:

```
having sum(quantity) = 
  (select max(sum_quan) from (select sum(Quantity) from orderrule group by Product_id))
```